# MVC 3.0 Portable Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, portable-areas

Are the Portable Areas Supported in MVC 3 ?
I have come across  "MVC-contrib" is it a HACK ?

Comment: you should tag your question better (language?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, portable areas are supported in mvc3.  Mvccontrib is not a hack, it's an assembly full of very cool and handy features that different developers have contributed to it.  It is quite common that features in "contrib" projects (not just mvc) eventually make it to the core project or framework.

Portable Areas are great, you should give them a try. Here is a [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/04/05/mvc-portable-areas-ndash-web-application-projects.aspx) to get you started:

Hope this helps,

-D